# How to distinguish "RTP over TCP" from "RTP over HTTP"?

Tags: streaming, rtp, rtsp

dear all:
I wanna ask some questions about streaming protocol.

1.If I get video streaming use RTSP the video streaming will be sent add [RTP header](http://www.networksorcery.com/enp/protocol/rtp.htm),but why some video streaming  also add RTP header via cgi command?

2.I could distinguish "RTP over TCP" from "RTP over UDP",but what differences between "RTP over TCP" and "RTP over HTTP"

I'm confuse ~

Answer (score 4, accepted):

i think you're confusing RTP over HTTP with RTSP over HTTP ( and therefore RTP too ): see http://developer.apple.com/quicktime/icefloe/dispatch028.html for more info.

Comment: hi ralf,thanks for the web site you provide! Maybe it is my first time touch RTP Protocol I spent 2 days to figure out it.Althought I couldn't understand these protocol totaly but still thank you. :)